# How to get the section header view's title when selecting a Cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` which has many `sections`, and each section has only 1 row.

What I want to do is that, when I click on a particular cell, the title of the header that corresponds to the cell should be changed.

I have set the section header using `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

How can I get the row header title inside the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: There are several ways to get that section title.  If you are using a datasource (NSArray most likely) for the section headers, you really just need one line of code to get it.  Don't jump on the first answer you read.  Read through them all and make sure you understand what each one is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest implementing both `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` (if both are implemented then iOS prefers `viewForHeaderInSection:`).  Then have your implementation of `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` create its view with the label and populate it with the result of `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     UIView *yourHeaderView;
     UILabel *someLabel;

     // set up the view + label

     // if self doesn't implement UITableViewDelegate, you can use tableView.delegate
     someLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

     return yourHeaderView;
}
```

Now when you're responding to a row tap, it's very easy to get the corresponding title:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSString *titleForHeader = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can get the header view for selected Index like :

```
UIView *headerView=[deviceTable headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
```

Then get the child from the headerView by looping through.like

```
for(UIView *view in headerView.subviews)
{
     if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *label=(UILabel *)v;
            NSString *text=label.text;
        }
}
```

**Edit:**
As Desdenova suggested :

```
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView=[deviceTable headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *title=headerView.textLabel.text;
```

Comment: No need to loop. `headerViewForSection` returns `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. And it has the property `textLabel`.

Comment: He didn't ask for the view.  He asked for the title in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: If my headerview is a custom view then how I can access my label text

Comment: @Desdenova: Yes ,you are right but you have to loop through if you have custom header.

Comment: @ElJay:He asked for the Header title . My code anyway will give that.

Comment: Yes it will, but it is far less efficient than just getting the title from the datasource used to populate the title.  Also, the OP asked for getting that value in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  You answer uses several lines of code and a loop to get it.  My answer uses one line of code and no loop.

Comment: @saji723:What are the elements inside your custom view ?

Comment: @ElJay:you are using array too. If it is not a custom header then my code also of two line .see my updated answer. what is the provision in your case for custom header . probably you also need to iterate for that .

Comment: The OP never mentioned a custom header.

Comment: @ElJay:Not in the question . But see in the comment below my answer.He has one custom label

Comment: UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView=[tblAlbums headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
        NSString *title=headerView.textLabel.text;here the title is getting nil;

Answer (score 4):

Swift solution:

```
let sectionHeaderView = table.headerViewForSection(indexPath.section)
let sectionTitle = sectionHeaderView?.textLabel?.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the datasource for the section header.  So whatever `NSArray` you have that hold the string values for the

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

just use that in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
NSString *titleForHeader = [myHeaderTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
```

Comment: There is a proper method for what's been asked.

Comment: @Desdenova - read the question.  He asked how to get the title of the current section header in didSelectRow...

Comment: So? Get the header view, get its text label and it is inside there.

Comment: Why get the view?  If all you need is the string value and you need that string value in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate, why are we talking about the viewForHeader?

Comment: Dumb? No sir it isn't. Mail apple if you don't like it. You can't assume that titles are in an array in the first place.

Comment: In programming in general and especially in iOS, you do not get stuff you don't need.  Always take the shortest route to what you need.  Resources and memory are limited, and you need to be as efficient as possible.  While getting the view and then digging inside that view to get a label and then getting the text property of that label is not a huge memory issue, the idea of doing that is wrong with you can get the same result by just getting the value of an NSString object that already exists in a datasource you already have.

Comment: If there are titles in a dynamic tableview, there HAS to be a datasource for those titles.  No need to ask Apple.  I have spent lots of time with Apple engineers and know the class reference for UITableView datasource and delegate very well sir.

Comment: @ElJay:- According to u, Do I need to create a seperate array for title also?

Comment: Yes.  I would.  If all you need is one label, just use that array and the titleForHeaderInSection method to populate that label.

Comment: I would not use viewForHeaderInSection at all (unless there is some special styling you need to do for that label).  Do things the most efficient and simplest way possible 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0) // put here your row or section number..
let myHeaderView = tableView.headerView(forSection:indexPath.section)
let title = myHeaderView?.textLabel?.text
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the section index by using:

```
indexpath.section
```

With the section index, you can simply duplicate what you have in `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` to get the section title.

Comment: There is a proper method for what's been asked.

Comment: @Desdenova - read the question.  He asked how to get the title of the current section header in didSelectRow...